# Java - Extract email address from requestURI with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract the email address from the requestURI with regex below is the email regex based on RFC-2822 and it works well with validations

```
private final transient String EMAIL_REGEX = 
            "^([^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]"
            + "+|\\x22([^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f])*\\x22)"
            + "(\\x2e([^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+"
            + "|\\x22([^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f])*\\x22))"
            + "*\\x40([^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+"
            + "|\\x5b([^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f])*\\x5d)"
            + "(\\x2e([^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]"
            + "+|\\x5b([^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f])*\\x5d))*$";
```

I'm trying to reuse the same regex to match and extract the email address from the URI `/something/users/myemail@email.com/somethingelse` , with `Matcher.group(0)` I get the output `/something/users/myemail@email.com` where as my intended output is only the email address from the URI.

Comment: Did you try removing `$` and `^`?

Comment: Just tried, returns the whole string, I wanted extract only the email address out..

Comment: Is there any reason the whole thing is in escapes?

Comment: Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/k3khtR). I added `/` to the two negated character classes at the start and end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with this regex update:

```
private static String EMAIL_REGEX =
        "([^/\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]"
        + "+|\\x22([^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f])*\\x22)"
        + "(\\x2e([^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+"
        + "|\\x22([^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f])*\\x22))"
        + "*\\x40([^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+"
        + "|\\x5b([^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f])*\\x5d)"
        + "(\\x2e([^/\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]"
        + "+|\\x5b([^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]|\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f])*\\x5d))*";
```

Please pay attention at the `[^/\\x00` at the beginning and on the second-to-last line.

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/k3khtR)

```
String s = "/something/users/myemail@email.com/somethingelse";         
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_REGEX).matcher(s);
while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
} // => myemail@email.com
```